# How do we access the latitude and longitude of a location returned by facebook graph API?

Tags: javascript, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

When we have made this query,

```
me?fields=location
```

the data that is returned is

```
{
  "location": {
    "id": "152971558114865",
    "name": "Kharagpur"
  },
  "id": "884016091689459"
}
```

My question is how do we get the latitude and longitude of this place using the location id?

I know i need to make this query for it. But I cannot understand how to use this?

`GET v2.6/...?fields={fieldname_of_type_Location} HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com`

Can someone write an exact code for this query?

**EDIT**

I wrote this code :

```
function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me', {fields: "id,birthday,email,gender,location,name"},function(response) {
  });


/* make the API call */
FB.api("...?fields={response.location}",
function (response2) {
  console.log(response2);
}
);
}
```

I get an error in response2.

```
message : Some of the aliases you request do not exist. 
type: OAuth Exception
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make another request like

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/' + id,'GET');
```

This will return an object having lat/lang

```
"location": {
   "latitude": ... , 
   "longitude": ...
},
```

**EDITED:**

javaScript code will be something like this (tested on Graph API tool explorer of facebook only):

```
function testAPI() {
    FB.api('/me', {
        fields: 'id,birthday,email,gender,location,name'
    }, function(response) {
        var location = reponse.location; //gets the location object you get from your response now
        FB.api('/' + location.id, {
            fields: 'location'
        }, function(locationResponse) {
            console.log(locationResponse); //will print your desired location object
        });

    });
```

If you want to explore it you can do it [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks :)

Comment: Great! Mind to accept this as correct answer? It'll be helpful for others in the future then.

Comment: You said that you tested that code in the Graph API tool, Did you input that javascript directly into the tool? I'm testing this tool as well but the only place i see to to test and input data and parameters is the textbox where the tool shows the method and fields of the request. Is there a place to input this javascript code to test?

Comment: NO, I've tested data in fields and written this method accordingly